# Gulp sort a css file (create, copy, delete problem)

Tags: css, sorting, gulp

I try to sort a css file.  I use several gulp plugins.  I use a tmp folder for sorting.
Can someone explain how to automate these steps :

```
1) Take style.css from folder CSS then sort it to folder CSS/tmp (same name) (task 1)
2) Delete style.css in CSS folder (task 2)
3) Copy style.css from CSS/tmp folder to CSS folder (task 3)
4) Delete style.css in CSS/tmp folder. (task 4)
```

Individually I can run theses tasks.  But chaining these with for example gulp.series and gulp.watch it run into errors.  Ideally each task would wait that the precedent task is completed (dont know how to).
When I run it with gulp.watch; the 1st time it is ok but after when I try to sort again the step 4 runs into errors because step 1 is in progress and style.css does not yet exist in CSS/tmp... (I think it is why..).

I am not programmer and dont know JS or nodejs just google it and tried and tried again to get theses tasks running individually.

Thank.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [pipe()](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/working-with-files)?

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-csscomb and https://github.com/csscomb/csscomb.js/blob/ce7ad831bd9b7fddb660c59afbbaf183c98d6ca7/config/csscomb.json it sorts your css properties.  Are you sorting properties or selectors?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which libs you're using. You can probably try using async/await. Check it [here](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/async-completion#using-async-await).

Maybe if you post your gulp code we can help you better.